# Date Number increases wrong in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, dayofweek

I have a problem with creating a calendar in JavaScript. I want to display dates from Monday to Sunday. So this is my DateSet function:

```
dateSets(year) {
          const today = new Date();
          year = today.getFullYear();

          let firstDayOfWeek = this.getDateOfWeek(this.currentWeekNumber, year);
          let dates = [];

          for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
              dates.push(
                  new Date(firstDayOfWeek.setDate(firstDayOfWeek.getDate() + i))
              );
          }
          return dates;
        }
```

`getDateOfWeek(this.currentWeekNumber, year)` gets the Monday of the week. But with this code displays `9/8/2021 10/8/2021 12/8/2021 15/8/2021 19/8/2021 24/8/2021 30/8/2021`.
So when I change the `i` in the for with `1` it displays like this but I cannot use this because I cannot get Monday: `10/8/2021 11/8/2021 12/8/2021 13/8/2021 14/8/2021 15/8/2021 16/8/2021`.

Comment: Simply add `today` to `dates` array just before the `for` loop and change `i` to `1`

Comment: Calling `.setDate()` on your first day of the week variable **changes** that Date instance, and does so on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Pointy  do you have a solution for this? How can I increase the date then?

Comment: Well you could leave the first day of week date unchanged, and make new dates with that as the basis. Each time through the loop, you'd make a new date and *then* add a number of days to the new one.